# Problem with my Bash script

Tags: bash, executable-jar

He all,
i have a problem with my bash script.
That's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar my_app.jar
echo "The present working directory is `pwd`"
```

If i exec it by ./script_name it work, but if i double click on it don't work, i got this error:
"Unable to access jarfile my_app.jar".
Then the pwd output is different !!!

My OS is MacOSX but i need to create a bash script that work in Linux too.

Comment: If this is for installing some thing, try tools like http://izpack.org/features/. You could create self-extracting binaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a graphical tool to execute the script, the current working directory is arbitrary. The current working directory is not a useful concept in graphical applications, and they usually don't use or change it. This means you must include the full path in the call to the `java` program, or change to the directory where the script is located. Unfortunately, [there is no good solution for the latter](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: I know, but i need to "install" this software in different OS so i can't use full path....any solutions ?

Comment: Do you really need a Bash script? At least on the Linux and OS X systems I use launching a Bash script from a file manager fires up a text editor and doesn't run the script. If it is a graphical application then you should create an application bundle for OS X, which contains all files required for running the application and can be moved around without problems.

Comment: Just my two cents, you should always use fully qualified paths in your scripts even if you just do a simple java = `which java` (better to have the actual path but this is a bandaid)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675078/problem-with-my-bash-script/3676496#3676496) suggested by [Shawn J. Goff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251561/shawn-j-goff) and commented on by [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) can be improved by employing modern `bash` command substitution syntax.  I'm assuming the script and jar are in the same folder:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar "$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)/my_app.jar"
echo The present working directory is $(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable $0 should hold the path to the script. You can use dirname to get the directory that the script is in.

```
java -jar `dirname $0`/my_app.jar
```

Comment: This will have trouble if anything in the path has a space (common in OS X) -- use `"$(dirname "$0")/my_app.jar"` instead.  Also, as Philipp pointed out, there are circumstances where this won't work (though it should be ok for double-clicking the script in the Finder).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so there are 2 issues you must solve:

1. Assuming your script and your jar are always installed in the same directory, problem 1 is to identify that directory.  That is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-in). Once you know the script's directory, you can reference your jar file relative to that.
2. Path to the system's installed `java` executable.  Ultimately just using bare `java` is straightforward and conventional and relies on the PATH being properly configured.  If that doesn't do it for you, just include an ordered list of the most common paths and see if they are executable using `if [ -e /usr/bin/java ]`, for example, running the first one your code finds.